# Div showing on clicking button twice in the initial state

Tags: html, jquery, css

In the very initial state, I need to click on Read More button TWICE to have the content below show. Weird - how do i fix this problem? I only want to click on Read More button once to show the content underneath it.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read More";
    }
    }
```

```css
   #myDIV {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>
    <div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV element.
    </div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read More</button>
    <p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
```

Comment: write `style="display:none"` to your `<div id="myDIV">` .Currently it go to else part first then `display = "none"` is assign to div so after second clicked it's showing div

Comment: Just did - thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's working on two clicks is that the DOM is ready but the script does not knows that the div's style is `display: none`.

There are two ways you can fix this:

**Using [window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)**

The `Window.getComputedStyle()` method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.

This way it will ensure that content will show in **one** click.

Demo:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var displayDiv = window.getComputedStyle(x).display; //this function
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  if (displayDiv === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read More";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>
  <div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV element.
  </div>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read More</button>
  <p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
</body>

</html>
```

**Using Inline styling** on the `div`

You could simply set the `display` to inline `style` as `display:none`.

This way it will ensure that `content` will show in **one** click.

Demo:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read More";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>
  <div id="myDIV" style="display: none;">
    This is my DIV element.
  </div>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read More</button>
  <p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should include a check if `myDiv`'s `display` style is empty.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (x.style.display === "none" || x.style.display === "") { // notice this line
    x.style.display = "block";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read More";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:
</p>
<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read More</button>

<p>
  <b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".
</p>
```